# Problems with stage.displayState (it's null even after assignments). Fullscreen AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fullscreen, cs4

Relevant things:

1. I had fullscreen code working before I did a security update on the flash player.
2. Nevertheless, I still can fullscreen Youtube right now
3. I'm doing the fullscreen activation in response to user clicks (therefore no security is blocking it AFAIK)
4. stage.displayState is null all the time, in the main timeline and even after assignments below.

Relevant code:

1) Set on the main timeline:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL; 
stage.align = StageAlign.RIGHT;
```

2) Set when a user clicks the fullscreen button:

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

/* ... */

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,modoFullScreen);

/* ... */

private function modoFullScreen(e:MouseEvent): void {
 try {
  stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
 }
 catch (e:SecurityError) {
  trace(e.toString());  
 }
}
```

3) Set when a user clicks the normal screen button:

```
/* Similar as above, but then I set */
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL
```

Comment: can you show the html embed code for the swf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you enable fullscreen when embedding?

> To enable full-screen mode, developers must add a new  and  tag parameter, allowFullScreen, to their HTML. This parameter defaults to false, or not allowing full screen. To allow full-screen, developers must set allowFullScreen to true in their / tags.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html

Comment: For some reason I recalled it was possible to go fullscreen while Testing Movie. Hadn't tried to deploy the HTML till now, and yes, doing your modifications on the published file worked, thank you.

I was pretty sure that you could go fullscreen in test movie, but now I see other sources on the net are telling that's not possible too.