# Flash content not go full screen

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997155/problems-with-stage-displaystate-its-null-even-after-assignments-fullscreen) but it is supposed to work as `swf` in the desktop, not in the html.

---

I am trying to make the content full screen via both at the beginning of the code and mouse event. However `stage.displayState` returns `null`. Here is how I do things;

at the beginning:
`stage.displayStatus = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;`

and then

```
fullScreenButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, DoFullScreen);

function DoFullScreen(e:MouseEvent)
{
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
}
```

and in the function, `stage.displayState` traced `null` as I said before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to target FP 11.3+ for `StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTION`

for below versions : `StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN`

**and you have to add that flash param in your html**

```
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
```

I added the sample [swf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53894534/sample.swf) and [fla](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53894534/sample.fla)

Comment: is param tag independent with that: _"...it is supposed to work as `swf` in the desktop, not in the html."_???

I have tried both `FULL_SCREEN` and `FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTION` but nothing happens.

Comment: if you are trying from flash debugger, it can not work, but if you run your code from exported swf it should work

Comment: My bad I assumed it starts as full screen. When I click the black rectangle, it goes FS.

Comment: i added fla, you can see it works like what you expect

Comment: Things get more and more ridiculous. I have two fla, contents and script etc. exactly same but one functionally handle FS the other is not. Maybe a restart will do the job. @Özgür And thanks for files but this is same what I am doing and failing.

Comment: it seems weird, if i can help with any condition again, feel free to ask

Comment: From a html page a swf can only go FS if the user clicks somewhere.