# SCORM API wrapper and Flash in full screen

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, scorm2004, scorm1.2

I lately posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774988/flash-content-not-go-full-screen) and unfortunately I couldn't figure it out why. Furthermore I haven't any solution for that. Today I realised I can switch between `NORMAL` and `FULL_SCREEN` without SCORM parts of the content (connect/disconnect, get/set, etc.). But when I check both Flash wrapper and Mike Rustici's edited API wrapper I was unable to find something about sceen and/or its size. Is there any feasible way to handle the situation?

Comment: You are talking about your problem like we all know every single aspect of the problem, we don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but for the record, SCORM has nothing to do with window size. It has no controls for window size.

Furthermore, Flash Player and all modern web browsers impose security limitations when going full screen (whether via SWF or HTML) to prevent bad people from spoofing a real site and getting you to input sensitive data, like passwords or credit card numbers.